# Ruby on rails - ActiveRecord query from array values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

i'm building a logging method.

in my update action i compare params from post value with actual db's value to catch changes and putting them in an array

**1° step** - Create an array and popolate with the name of change
    modificati = Array.new

```
modificati.push("nome") if @clienti.nome != params[:clienti][:nome]
modificati.push('email') if @clienti.email != params[:clienti][:email]
..... the same for every field .....
```

**2° step** is to log only changed field, so i create a new array with changes

```
modifiche = Array.new

modificati.each do |m|
    modifiche.push( "#{m} : #{@clienti.m} >>  - ")
end
```

But it's not working, can someone help me please?
My goal is to put this in array :

"nome : old_value_from_db >> new_value_from_post"

but the error is:

**undefined method `m' for #**

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call the attribute (or method) from `@client`, like:

```
modificati.each do |m|
  modifiche.push( "#{m} : #{@client.public_send(m.to_sym)} >>  - ")
end
```

EDIT: if @client is an active record object you can use `@client.changes` before saving to track any changes made on object's attributes.

EDIT: filling the second value, you can dup @client before mutating it:

```
client_before = @clienti.dup
.
.
.
# update @clienti, then
.
.
modifiche = []
modificati.each do |m|
  modifiche.push( "#{m} : #{client_before.public_send(m.to_sym)} >>  #{@clienti.public_send(m.to_sym)} ")
end
```

Comment: `send` is definitely not recommended. Better to use `public_send`

Comment: can you help me also for the second attribute? modifiche.push( "#{m} : #{@clienti.public_send(m.to_sym)} >>  - #{params[:clienti][public_send(m.to_sym)]} ")

Comment: answer added to the post. Hope you find it helpful

Comment: Thanks jhon, but it's not my goal..... the second  value must be like "params[:clienti][:nome]" and "nome" is from array --> 'm' like in first attribute

Comment: sure, you can change the send value to params, that's valid too. I'm assuming that your're doing something like `@clienti.update_attributes(params[:client])` , that's why I suggested to dup the object before changing it with params values

Comment: how can i do it? with " #{params[:clienti][:public_send(m.to_sym)]} " i have "syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ']' ...{params[:clienti][:public_send(m.to_sym)]} ") ... ^ "

Comment: i need to dinamically retrieve params from post values

Comment: you just need to do `#{params[:clienti][m]}`